# Configure virtual host for custom directory

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

I have a web application installed in '/var' in a folder called 'myapp' in a CentOs 6 vps, and i have a sub-domain that points to the server IP, and i need that sub-domain to point to that '/var/myapp' folder. so I created a .conf file in '/etc/httpd/conf.d' folder with the virtual host declaration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName app.mydomain.com
        DocumentRoot "/var/myapp/"
        <Directory /var/myapp/>
                AllowOverride all
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
                AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
                Order Deny,Allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But it still redirects me to the Apache welcome page, which should appear when there is nothing in 'www' folder.

Comment: Did you reload (or restart) Apache?

Comment: @sebasth Yes, i did.

Comment: Do you have the `NameVirtualHost *:80` that is still required in RHEL6's `httpd` 2.2?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Yes, it's the first line in my .conf file.

Comment: Don't known how apache configured on CentOs, but sure you have to find default virtualhost what catches requests before your config. Search for ServerName * or it absence for another virtualhost.